# PySpark - unable to save data

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running Spark in standalone mode

rdd

```
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "white,black,yellow"
}
```

new rdd

```
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "white"
}
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "black"
}
{
    "name": "adam",
    "gender": "male",
    "new_column": "yellow"
}
```

Codes are below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.json("test.json")




df2 = df.withColumn("new_column", F.explode(F.split("new_column", ",")))
df2.write.format('json').save('final')
```

Schema

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_column: string (nullable = true)
```

No error when i run the file ..

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=test.py pyspark
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/opt/spark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/09/17 10:56:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/09/17 10:56:01 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
21/09/17 10:56:01 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021 15:33:00)
Spark context Web UI available at http://root1-System-Product-Name:4042
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1631872561867).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

can someone explain ?

Also, please what is the best way to save a pysaprk dataframe for further use?

Thanks a lot!

A few things to notice:

I'm working with pyspark 3.1.1

Python version 3.6.9

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've already saved your data next to `test.json`. Remember, it's a **directory** with one or more files inside.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can save the file as csv

```
df2.coalesce(1).write.option("header",true).option("delimiter","|").csv("file:///local path")
```

Comment: Same thing - I saved no data at all. I trie with three methods, but none of them worked.